# Opening PDF in browser taking huge time using java

Tags: java, pdf

I'm facing performance issue while opening pdf files in browser.It is taking very huge to time to open.Our pdf files are scanned images. So is there any alternative solution for this. Here is my sample code.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
// Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;
while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
out.write(buf, 0, count);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

Here i'm rendering outstream to browser.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be the problem. Why do you think it has anything to do with java? Is there a comparsion with another technology/method?

Comment: Can you quantify your analysis?  How big are the files, and how long is the *download* taking (rather than opening)?